# Python - Linked List node comparision requires additional dereferencing

Tags: python, linked-list

I am using Python 3.6.3. I am trying to write a simple Linked List in Python. Here is my code:

```
    class Node(object):
    """Represents a node within a linked list"""
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.stuff = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stuff)

class LinkedList(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size=0

    def append(self, data):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = Node(data)
            return
        else:
            n=self.head
            while n.next:
                n = n.next

            new_node = Node(data)
            n.next = new_node
            return

    def insertAfter(self, data, newNode):
        if not self.head:
            return
        else:
            n=self.head
            while n and n.stuff != data:
                n = n.next

            if not n:
                return
            else:
                newNode.next = n.next
                n.next = newNode
                return

    def printlist(self):
        if not self.head:
            print("List is empty")
            return
        else:
            n = self.head
            while n:
                print(str(n))
                n = n.next
        return

ll = LinkedList()
ll.append(Node("1"))
ll.append(Node("2"))
ll.append(Node("3"))
ll.insertAfter("2", Node("2.5"))
ll.printlist()
```

I expect it to print:

```
1
2
2.5
3
```

But, instead it prints:

```
1
2
3
```

After debugging, I realized that changing this line in the insertAfter method:

```
while n and n.stuff != data:
```

to:

```
while n and n.stuff.stuff != data:
```

prints the expected output. 
I don't understand why it is doing this. 
Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are not adding 1, 2, 3 to the `LinkedList` and letting it create a `Node` to wrap each. You are adding a `Node` whose `stuff` variable is 1, 2, and 3. When you call the append method to add each `Node`, they get wrapped in another `Node` by the `append` method. Therefore you need to call `Node.stuff.stuff` to access the actual element that is stored.

Look at what your `append` method is actually doing. It accepts some parameter `data` and then creates a `Node` with either the line `self.head = Node(data)` or the line `new_node = Node(data)`, depending on if the `LinkedList` already has a head `Node` or not.

Change `ll.append(Node("1"))` to just `ll.append("1")`. Alternatively, change your append method to assume it is being passed a Node object. **The first solution is much more preferable** as the `Node` class has little use outside the context of the `LinkedList` class and the `LinkedList` doesn't work unless it is populated with `Nodes` anyways; it seems like extra work to make the user of the `LinkedList` class have to create a `Node` every single time.

EDIT: Also what is the reason you are passing in numbers as strings? You don't need to put 1, 2, 2.5, and 3 in quotes unless you specifically want them to be strings- but if so, why?

Comment: I feel so silly now!! I had made that change while I was playing around with things and had fogotten that I had made that change in the append method.
Thank you.